# HighCharts Export server "invalid" input data

Tags: highcharts

I'm testing the HighCharts Export server with a load of 1000 requests. All the requests are the same so I should receive the same output for the 1000 tests. The JSON request is the following:

```
{
    "type": "png",
    "scale": 1,
    "infile": {
        "chart": {
            "backgroundColor": null,
            "width": 1000,
            "height": 200,
            "style": {
                "fontFamily": "Arial"
            }
        },
        "title": {
            "text": ""
        },
        "plotOptions": {
            "bar": {
                "pointPadding": 0,
                "borderWidth": 0,
                "dataLabels": {
                    "enabled": false,
                    "fontWeight": "normal"
                }
            }
        },
        "xAxis": {
            "tickWidth": 0,
            "gridLineColor": "#E2E8ED",
            "categories": ["Jan", "Fév", "Mar", "Avr", "Mai", "Juin", "Juil", "Aoû", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Déc"],
            "labels": {
                "enabled": true,
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "14px",
                    "color": "#52626F"
                }
            }
        },
        "yAxis": {
            "min": -4,
            "max": 10,
            "tickInterval": 2,
            "labels": {
                "format": "{value}%",
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "14px",
                    "color": "#52626F"
                }
            },
            "title": {
                "text": null
            }
        },
        "series": [{
                "name": "xxx",
                "type": "column",
                "color": "#C20044",
                "pointWidth": 43,
                "data": [3.65, 2.70, 1.40, -0.85, 0.25, -2.65, 1.40, -3.40, -1.30, 3.45, 1.35, -2.35]
            },
            {
                "name": "xxx",
                "type": "line",
                "color": "#52626F",
                "lineWidth": 1.5,
                "marker": {
                    "enabled": false
                },
                "data": [3.65, 6.35, 7.75, 6.90, 7.15, 4.50, 5.90, 2.50, 1.20, 4.65, 6.00, 3.65]
            },
            {
                "showInLegend": false,
                "lineWidth": 0,
                "data": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                "marker": {
                    "enabled": false
                }
            }
        ],
        "legend": {
            "enabled": true,
            "layout": "vertical",
            "align": "right",
            "verticalAlign": "middle",
            "margin": 65,
            "itemMarginBottom": 6,
            "itemMarginTop": 6,
            "symbolRadius": 0,
            "style": {
                "fontSize": "14px",
                "color": "#52626F"
            }
        },
        "credits": {
            "enabled": false
        }
    }
}
```

And the output is this chart: [image: Column chart with line]

There is nothing wrong with the output itself but after a while the HighCharts Server returns an error which says that the input data was invalid.
**[error] work 9fa383e8bd0f44f3a1e50dc95b13df71 could not be completed, sending: error when performing chart generation: please check your input data**. However the request hasn't been changed. Mostly the error occurs when we're halfway.

I run the export server using the following command `highcharts-export-server --enableServer 1 --port 8080 --workers 20 --workLimit 200`
A worklimit of 200 seems me a good number because we cross this amount of requests.

Does anyone have an idea why it suddenly doesn't want to process the request and says I need to check my input data?

Btw. The export server is running in a docker container, but I think that does not cause the problem.

Comment: Could you provide some more information about how you performed the testing? I'm not able to reproduce this issue by launching request via `curl` command in 1000 long loop (each iteration launches separate process) in batch file on Windows. My command is similar to the one shown in the official doc: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/blob/master/README.md